# Flutter - iOS - Save username and password into webcredentials for autofill

Tags: ios, flutter, autofill

We are trying to create a sample application with username and password fields. Our goal is to save the entered username and password in the web credential manager of iOS and reuse the credentials using the autofill option.

Currently, we are able to see stored credentials while typing in the username but unable to save new credentials. We have enabled Associated Domains as per the documentation. Please note that we are trying to achieve this using **Flutter** (version 1.22.1 stable channel).

Appreciate your thoughts and inputs.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Any solution yet?